# SlideToggle multiple elements independently

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I need some help with SlideToggle.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <figure class="left"><img src="images/slider/img3.jpg" alt="" width="270" height="152" /><a href="#" class="image-overlay"></a></figure>
        <div class="meta">
            <h2>Superior Double Room</h2>
            <p>Prices are per room<br />20 % VAT Included in price</p>
            <p>Non-refundable<br />Full English breakfast $ 24.80 </p>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="more info" class="more-info">+ more info</a>
        </div>
        <div class="room-information">
            <div class="row">
                <span class="first">Max:</span>
                <span class="second"><img src="images/ico/person.png" alt="" /><img src="images/ico/person.png" alt="" /></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <span class="first">Price:</span>
                <span class="second">$ 55</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <span class="first">Rooms:</span>
                <span class="second">01</span>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="gradient-button" title="Book">Book</a>
        </div>
        <div class="more-information">
            <p>Stylish and individually designed room featuring a satellite TV, mini bar and a 24-hour room service menu.</p>
            <p><strong>Room Facilities:</strong> Safety Deposit Box, Air Conditioning, Desk, Ironing Facilities, Seating Area, Heating, Shower, Bath, Hairdryer, Toilet, Bathroom, Pay-per-view Channels, TV, Telephone</p>
            <p><strong>Bed Size(s):</strong> 1 Double </p>
            <p><strong>Room Size:</strong>  16 square metres</p>
        </div>
    </li>

        <li>
        <figure class="left"><img src="images/slider/img3.jpg" alt="" width="270" height="152" /><a href="#" class="image-overlay"></a></figure>
        <div class="meta">
            <h2>Superior Double Room</h2>
            <p>Prices are per room<br />20 % VAT Included in price</p>
            <p>Non-refundable<br />Full English breakfast $ 24.80 </p>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="more info" class="more-info">+ more info</a>
        </div>
        <div class="room-information">
            <div class="row">
                <span class="first">Max:</span>
                <span class="second"><img src="images/ico/person.png" alt="" /><img src="images/ico/person.png" alt="" /></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <span class="first">Price:</span>
                <span class="second">$ 55</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <span class="first">Rooms:</span>
                <span class="second">01</span>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="gradient-button" title="Book">Book</a>
        </div>
        <div class="more-information">
            <p>Stylish and individually designed room featuring a satellite TV, mini bar and a 24-hour room service menu.</p>
            <p><strong>Room Facilities:</strong> Safety Deposit Box, Air Conditioning, Desk, Ironing Facilities, Seating Area, Heating, Shower, Bath, Hairdryer, Toilet, Bathroom, Pay-per-view Channels, TV, Telephone</p>
            <p><strong>Bed Size(s):</strong> 1 Double </p>
            <p><strong>Room Size:</strong>  16 square metres</p>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".more-information").slideUp();
        $(".more-info").click(function() {
        var txt = $(".more-information").is(':visible') ? '+ more info' : ' - less info';
        $(".more-info").text(txt);
        $(".more-information").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

By clicking in "more-info" link I need to open "more-information" div. Now it toggles all at once, how can I achieve to toggle each independently?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go" [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvVNX/1)

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".more-information").slideUp();
$(".more-info").click(function() {
    var moreinformation = $(this).closest("li").find(".more-information");
        var txt = moreinformation.is(':visible') ? '+ more info' : ' - less info';
        $(this).text(txt);
        moreinformation.slideToggle("slow");
    });
});​
```

Because roXon requested:

```
moreinformation.stop(true, true).slideToggle("slow");
```

Will prevent bad things happening when clicking the link multiple times in quick succession.

Comment: He asked how to toggle independently. How he wants the animations to function during these cases is up to him. Edit- Person deleted their comment.

Comment: Ok, fair enough :) than you could just put an '*' in your answer and point the OP to what's missing......... (**accidentally removed my first comment that was:**) fast-click the toggle button and read what you see.

Comment: Thank you very much, James. I appreciate it a lot.